# Ruby Array: TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array:

```
row = [:text_field,
 [{:text=>
    "I<NLDSPECI20142999999990<<<<<86503101F2403096NLD<<<<<<<<<<<8DE<BRUIJN<<WILLEKE<LISELOTTE<<",
   :value=>"999999990",
   :@derived=>"false",
   :@id=>"_7a88b4df-8730-46d9-9a13-6494940fcfce-fg-1-fd-1",
   :@name=>"CitizenServiceNumber",
   :@score=>"1"},
  {:text=>
    "I<NLDSPECI20142999999990<<<<<86503101F2403096NLD<<<<<<<<<<<8DE<BRUIJN<<WILLEKE<LISELOTTE<<",
   :value=>"NLD",
   :@derived=>"false",
   :@id=>"_7a88b4df-8730-46d9-9a13-6494940fcfce-fg-1-fd-2",
   :@name=>"CountryCode",
   :@score=>"1"}]]
```

When I call:

```
row.each {|row_info| row_info[:@name]}
```

I get an error that says:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: `row[1].map { |ri| ri[:@name] }`

Comment: Can you come up with a smaller example?

Comment: Since the elements in array are not in similar format, first sanitize the array and then performing operations is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collection you are looking to iterate is in `row[1]` rather than `row`

```
row[1].map { |ri| ri[:@name] }
#=> ["CitizenServiceNumber", "CountryCode", "DocumentNumber", "DocumentType", "Gender", "GivenNames", "Initials", "Nationality", "Prefixes", "Surname"]
```

Answer (score 3):

`:text_field` is an instance of `Symbol` class. It does not respond to `[]` method.

The following won't throw any exceptions, tho it will do nothing:

```
row.last.each {|row_info| row_info[:@name]}
```